# JavaFx 8 WebEngine - Caching images via user data directory?

Tags: image, caching, local-storage, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I am new to JavaFx and tried to implement its browser in my application. Since reloading all images on every new startup is quite time-consuming, **I'd like to store them in some cache directory**, but have been failing to do so. I tried using `setUserDataDirectory(...)`, but that only leads to an empty folder called `localstorage` and an empty `.lock` file being created.

I then found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968471/caching-in-javafx-webview), but firstly, I am not yet allowed to comment there and secondly, it only seems to address JavaFx 2.2. Does what has been posted there still hold true for JavaFx 8? If so: is there a simple way to implement such a `URLConnection` cache?

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

So, after 2 days of digging into the problem and learning about the `URLConnection` class, I finally was able to come up with my own (presumably crude) implementation which I'd like to share here in case anyone with as little knowledge as I happens to stumble over this thread. Again, the basic idea was to place only specific file types in a cache, not everything. I chose to store `jpg`, `png`, `gif` and `js` files as I thought them to be the most load-heavy ones, though every other file format should be possible, too.
First things first: `browser.getEngine().setUserDataDirectory(...)` definitely does NOT do the job. I still have no clue, what it is good for, but it's certainly not storing image files %)

Instead, what I did was basically creating 5 classes:

- `CachedResource`: Consists of a `byte[]` array holding a resource's raw data and some meta info (header fields, lastModified)
- `ResourceCache`: Holds all currently cached resource objects.
- `MyHttpUrlConnection` (extends `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`): A wrapper class that is responsible for retrieving the file that its given URL points to. It does all the network magic.
- `CachedUrlConnection` (extends `java.net.URLConnection`): An (almost) empty implementation that already has all the data we need and only waits for the system to call it.
- `MyUrlConnectionHandler` (extends `sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler`): This class is registered at application start and decides when to use which `URLConnection` (see below).

The `ResourceCache`, `CachedResource` and `CachedUrlConnection` classes are fairly small and easy to write. I designed the resource cache to map the resource of a url with its corresponding `CachedResource` object, thus: `ConcurrentHashMap<URL, CachedResource>` plus a getter and an `addResource(...)` function. I added some other stuff to it like storing files locally, but this leads off-topic.

I then implemented the `CachedUrlConnection` class as follows:

```
public class CachedUrlConnection extends URLConnection {

    private CachedResource resource;
    private ByteArrayInputStream inputStream;

    /* Constructors */
    public CachedUrlConnection(URL url, CachedResource resource) throws IOException {
        super(url);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(resource.getByteData());
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
        // No need to do anything.
    }

    /* Object Methods */

    /* Getters and Setters */
    @Override
    public String getHeaderField(int index) { ... }

    @Override
    public String getHeaderField(String key) { ... }

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> getHeaderFields() { ... }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return inputStream; // <---- Here, the system can grab the data.
    }
}
```

When looking at the sourcecode of URLConnection (for example [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/net/URLConnection.java#URLConnection)), you will quickly notice that most of its method implementations are dummies that either return `null` or throw an  `UnknownServiceException`.

**This is important: I don't know exactly which of these you need to implement!**

In order to find out, I used the `MyHttpUrlConnection` class and added to almost every function

```
System.out.println("function xyz called!");
super.xyz();
```

but I was lazy and didn't check all of them. So far, everything seems to be working fine %)

The next class was `MyHttpUrlConnection`. I am not 100% sure if I actually needed to overwrite the `HttpURLConnection` class, but I did so anyway, because it has a `protected` constructor that will implicitely be called with a new `sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler`. That handler would obviously not follow our http policy, so I just wanted to be certain (cf. [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.%3Cinit%3E%28java.net.URL%2Cjava.net.Proxy%29) line 801). The class thus looks rather empty:

```
public class MyHttpUrlConnection extends HttpURLConnection {

    protected MyHttpUrlConnection(URL url, Handler handler) {
        this(url, null, handler);
    }

    public MyHttpUrlConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) {
        this(url, proxy, new MyUrlConnectionHandler()); // <--- No way sneaking around^^
    }

    protected MyHttpUrlConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy, Handler handler) {
        super(url, proxy, handler);
    }

    public MyHttpUrlConnection(URL url, String host, int port) {
        this(url, new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(host, port))); // Taken over from the HttpURLConnection sourcecode.
    }
}
```

Now comes the most important part: the `MyUrlConnectionHandler`. Again, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968471/caching-in-javafx-webview) on where to put it. All the class itself needs is to overwrite the `openConnection(URL, Proxy)` function. Before posting my code, I will give you a run-through of what it does.

1. If the given URL is a jpg, png, ... file:
2. Use a `MyHttpUrlConnection` object to get the resource's last date of modification on the server. this should only call the header and NOT the entire resource. Otherwise, we wouldn't have won anything. Credits go to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691825/android-how-to-know-file-located-in-web-server-is-modified). **I am not completely sure**, though, whether I'm closing the `URLConnection` properly here. Better double-check if in doubt ;)
3. If there is no resource in the cache OR the resource in the cache is out of date:
4. Close the mini connection and open a "proper" one to download the whole thing.
5. Create a new `CachedResource` object and add it to the cache.
6. Close that new connection, too.
7. Return a new `CachedUrlConnection` object that holds the data. This might seem a bit stupid, as we already have everything, but the function needs to return a `URLConnection`.
8. If there is any exception or we simply did not deal with a jpg, png, ... file, return a "default" `MyHttpUrlConnection` object to process the URL normally.

And the corresponding code looks as follows. Note that I used the Apache `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`:

```
@Override
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {

    try {

        // Is this some resource that we'd like to cache?
        if (ResourceCache.isCachableURL(url)) {

            // Retrieve whatever is in the cache first.
            ResourceCache cache = ResourceCache.getInstance();
            CachedResource resource = cache.getCachedResource(url);

            // Open a connection to the server to at least check for the last-modified field.
            MyHttpUrlConnection conn = new MyHttpUrlConnection(url, this); // Don't use URL#openConnection to avoid looping!
            conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            conn.connect();
            long lastModified = conn.getLastModified();

            // Did we get the last-modified value at all?
            if (lastModified == 0) {
                throw new Exception("No last-modified value could be read! \n\t" + url);
            }

            // Resource not cached or out of date?
            if (resource == null || resource.getLastModified() < lastModified) {

                conn = new MyHttpUrlConnection(url, this);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
                Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(input); 

                resource = new CachedResource(url.getFile(), data, headerFields, lastModified); // I use url.getFile() to store the file on my hard drive.
                cache.addCachedResource(url, resource);
            }

            return new CachedUrlConnection(url, resource);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return the default HttpURLConnection in our wrapper class.
    return new MyHttpUrlConnection(url, proxy, this);
}
```

**One last thing:** To be on the safe side, NEVER use the `URL#openConnection` method inside the `MyUrlConnectionHandler#openConnection` function. Writing it down this way makes it pretty obvious why, but today, it took me quite a while to figure out where the infinite loop was coming from %) Use the constructor and call `connect()` instead.

I hope this will ever help anyone, otherwise it has been a good exercise for me ^^

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is still valid. If you want to implement that for just a specific purpose it is not so difficult but a general purpose solution would be more challenging.

Comment: Well for now I'd be happy if I could at least store the load-heavy image files on my hard drive and then load them from there. However, I have no clue how to do that. Would it be possible to extend the `net.www.protocol.http.Handler` or `HttpURLConnection` and "simply" change a bit of their functionality to suit my needs? (I only need to support http at the moment.)